# Make time-period observations into annual observations in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling, replicate

I have a dataset (df1) on hundreds of national crises, where each observation is a crisis event at the country level with a start and an end date. I also have the date when the crisis was announced (yyyy-mm-dd format), and a bunch of other crisis characteristics.

```
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(eventID=c(1,2,3,4), country=c("ALB","ALB","ARG","ARG"), start=c(1994, 1998, 1998, 1991), end=c(1996,1999,1999,1993), announcement=c("1994-11-01","1998-03-01","1998-07-01","1992-01-01"), x1=c(6,2,8,7), x2=c("a","q","k","b")))

eventID   country    start    end      announcement     x1      x2 
1         ALB        1994     1996     1994-11-01       6       a
2         ALB        1998     1999     1998-03-01       2       q
3         ARG        1998     1999     1998-07-01       8       k
4         ARG        1991     1993     1992-01-01       7       b
```

I need to make df2, a panel of countries with annual observations from the earliest "start" year to the latest "end" year. I want to have a dummy variable, "crisis", that equals 1 for the years between "start" and "end" in df1, and 0 otherwise. I want "announcement" to contain the announcement date in df1 for the year with an announcement, and "NA" otherwise. I would like the extra crisis characteristics, x1 and x2, to show up for crisis years to which they correspond, and "NA" otherwise.

I also need observations for each country for years in which no country has a crisis (in df2: 1997).

```
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(year=c(1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999), country=c("ALB","ALB","ALB","ALB","ALB","ALB","ALB","ALB","ALB","ARG","ARG","ARG","ARG","ARG","ARG","ARG","ARG","ARG"),crisis=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1), announcement=c(NA, NA,NA,"1994-11-01",NA,NA,NA,"1998-03-01",NA,NA,"1992-01-01",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"1998-07-01"), x1=c(NA,NA,NA,6,6,6,NA,2,2,8,8,8,NA,NA,NA,NA,7,7), x2=c(NA,NA,NA,"a","a","a",NA,"q","q","k","k","k",NA,NA,NA,NA,"b","b")))

year      country    crisis   announcement    x1       x2
1991      ALB        0        NA              NA       NA
1992      ALB        0        NA              NA       NA
1993      ALB        0        NA              NA       NA
1994      ALB        1        1994-11-01      6        a
1995      ALB        1        NA              6        a
1996      ALB        1        NA              6        a
1997      ALB        0        NA              NA       NA
1998      ALB        1        1998-03-01      2        q
1999      ALB        1        NA              2        q
1991      ARG        1        NA              8        k
1992      ARG        1        1992-01-01      8        k
1993      ARG        1        NA              8        k
1994      ARG        0        NA              NA       NA
1995      ARG        0        NA              NA       NA
1996      ARG        0        NA              NA       NA
1997      ARG        0        NA              NA       NA
1998      ARG        1        1998-07-01      7        b
1999      ARG        1        NA              7        b
```

I would love any suggestions! I'm stumped as to how to replicate the observations for each year, but only include x1 and x2 values when my new "crisis" dummy = 1

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide `dput()` or `data.frame()` with your example data?

Answer (score 0):

Making use of dplyr and tidyr this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(cbind(eventID=c(1,2,3,4), country=c("ALB","ALB","ARG","ARG"), start=c(1994, 1998, 1998, 1991), end=c(1996,1999,1999,1993), announcement=c("1994-11-01","1998-03-01","1998-07-01","1992-01-01"), x1=c(6,2,8,7), x2=c("a","q","k","b")))

df1 %>% 
  mutate(year = factor(start, levels = min(start):max(end))) %>% 
  complete(year, country) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>% 
  arrange(country, year) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  fill(eventID, end, x1, x2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(across(c(eventID, end, x1, x2), ~ ifelse(end < year, NA, .)),
         crisis = as.numeric(!is.na(eventID)))
#> # A tibble: 18 x 9
#>     year country eventID start end   announcement x1    x2    crisis
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>        <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1  1991 ALB     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>  <NA>       0
#>  2  1992 ALB     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>  <NA>       0
#>  3  1993 ALB     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>  <NA>       0
#>  4  1994 ALB     1       1994  1996  1994-11-01   6     a          1
#>  5  1995 ALB     1       <NA>  1996  <NA>         6     a          1
#>  6  1996 ALB     1       <NA>  1996  <NA>         6     a          1
#>  7  1997 ALB     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>  <NA>       0
#>  8  1998 ALB     2       1998  1999  1998-03-01   2     q          1
#>  9  1999 ALB     2       <NA>  1999  <NA>         2     q          1
#> 10  1991 ARG     4       1991  1993  1992-01-01   7     b          1
#> 11  1992 ARG     4       <NA>  1993  <NA>         7     b          1
#> 12  1993 ARG     4       <NA>  1993  <NA>         7     b          1
#> 13  1994 ARG     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>  <NA>       0
#> 14  1995 ARG     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>  <NA>       0
#> 15  1996 ARG     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>  <NA>       0
#> 16  1997 ARG     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>  <NA>       0
#> 17  1998 ARG     3       1998  1999  1998-07-01   8     k          1
#> 18  1999 ARG     3       <NA>  1999  <NA>         8     k          1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! When I try your exact code, I end up with crisis data filled in for years where there wasn't a crisis (crisis = 1, x1 and x2 filled in) like for row 7 (1997 ALB). eventID is only blank for the first three rows, so crisis is coded 1 for all years except those first three. Any ideas?

Comment: For some reason, the `ifelse(end < year, NA, .)` argument isn't working (even when I make sure `year` is numeric). Ex: `end` = 1996 and `year` = 1997, but `NA` isn't returned

Comment: Hi. First. I just made an edit and removed the left_join. Instead I add year as a factor to get all years. Additionally I group_by country before filling. At least for the sample data these changes do have any impact on the final result, nevertheless this should make the code more robust for more general cases. Second. Concerning your questions. Hard to tell. 1. As far as I get it the result of my code for the sample data equals your desired output. 2. No clue why the ifelse fails in your case.